# List comprehension and in place methods

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am just trying to understand what happens during list comprehension. Some methods which work on lists 'in-place' don't seem to work when applied in a list comprehension:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
i1 = id(a[0])

for i in a: i.reverse()
>>> [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]  # Works
print i1 == id(a[0])  # True, same memory address

a = [i.reverse() for i in a]
>>> [None, None]  # Doesn't work
print i1 == id(a[0])  # False, new memory address

a = [i[::-1] for i in a]
>>> [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]]  # Works!
print i1 == id(a[0])  # False
```

I am guessing this has something to do with all the elements getting copied to a different memory space. Why does `i[::-1]` work whereas `i.reverse()` doesn't?

Comment: `i[::-1]` returns new list while `reverse()` returns `None`.

Comment: It's like writing `[None for i in a]`, since `a` contains two elements, you're getting `[None, None]`.

Comment: Do `[i.reverse() or i for i in a]` to make the second work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i.reverse()` reverses the array in place and doesn't return anything, meaning it returns `None` type. That way you obtain `[None, None]` from list comprehension and previous arrays' elements are reversed at the same time.

These two shouldn't be mixed, either use a `for` and `x.reverse()`, or use `reversed(x)` or `x[::-1]` in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

`i.reverse()` reverses the list in-place and returns `None`.

*What the docs say:*

> `list.reverse()`
>
> Reverse the elements of the list, in place

vs.

> `reversed(seq)`
>
> Return a reverse iterator. seq must be an object which has a
>   `__reversed__()` method or supports the sequence protocol
>   (*the `__len__()` method and the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments starting at `0`*).

**Examples:**

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(xs)
140625121860208
>>> ys = xs[::-1]
>>> id(ys)
140625121924088
```

Slicing creates a new list.

```
>>> xs.reverse()
>>> xs
[3, 2, 1]
>>> id(xs)
140625121860208
```

In-place sorting/reversing retains the original list.

```
>>> zs = list(reversed(xs))
>>> zs
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(zs)
140625121976400
```

`reversed()` returns an iterator; which when turns into a list creates a new list! If you have a read of [PEP 0322 -- Reverse Iteration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/#proposal) you'll note that `reversed()` does not create a new data structure but simply iteratoes over the sequence in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you intend:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> [list(reversed(i)) for i in a]
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]]
```

List comprehension always returns a new list, so using the in-place `reverse`
method just returns the return value of `reverse`, which is `None`.

The function `reversed()` gives you an new iterator. Converting it to
a list is for your example the same as:

```
>>> [i[::-1] for i in a]
```

Even though they look very similar, it is important to distinguish both,
the function `reversed()` and the method `obj.reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

`list.reverse` reverses a list in place, and return `None`. 
while slice `a[::-1]` creates another list and return as value.

list comprehension will take the `return value` of each expression.